# Unity Hololens2 Build Errors

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens

I try to build my Hololens 2 application but i get errors which i can not solve.
When I try to test the application with the Unity play button, it works as expected. I have also tried the MRTK sample scene, which also works only through the play button, but does not when I try to build it.

**Build Errors:**

```
Library\PackageCache\com.microsoft.mixedreality.toolkit.foundation@251fc689f36f\Providers\WindowsMixedReality\XRSDK\WindowsMixedRealityDeviceManager.cs(404,128): error CS0104: 'Handedness' is an ambiguous reference between 'Microsoft.MixedReality.Input.Handedness' and 'Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Utilities.Handedness'
```

```
Error building Player because scripts had compiler errors
```

```
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 2 errors
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x002da] in <1135c66e5f4c41a7831fa5798849d8b6>:0 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00080] in <1135c66e5f4c41a7831fa5798849d8b6>:0 
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

I tried to update the MRTK with the MixedRealityFeatureTool and did the [Mixed Reality Toolkit-Set Up](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/learn-mrtk-tutorials/) as described in the tutorial. But i still get the errors, which means i can not test it on the Hololens 2.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I had this problem but I was able to fix the error by going to the script in the specified path (Library\PackageCache\com.microsoft.mixedreality.toolkit.foundation@251fc689f36f\Providers\WindowsMixedReality\XRSDK\WindowsMixedRealityDeviceManager.cs) in the error, going into the error line (404) and changing Handedness to 'Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Utilities.Handedness'

Comment: I do not know exactly why this "error" is in the code (although I have the latest version etc.), but now it works. Hopefully this will be changed in a new version.
Thank you very much for the quick help!

Comment: This isn't really needed. Also causes headaches if you are in a team and set ignore on the Library folder which as standard.

Answer (score 5):

Also happening for me and only happened when upgraded to MRTK 2.8.
As we are developing for HoloLens, there is no need for the MixedReality.Input package, which is causing the conflict. Simply remove that from the Package Manager.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I just wanted to keep the possibility for other inputs open, which would no longer be possible without the package. So i think we have to wait for changes in the MRTK.

Comment: hey guys, any news on this? Especially if we want to keep the Input package as @Alex suggested?

Comment: @Traian Unfortunately, I still have not found a solution.